# How do I use roll, pitch and yaw to fuse in with my 3-D points points to make a 3-D surface?

Tags: python, numpy, opengl, matrix, rotation

I have a array of 3-D points in a way like that each 24 set of 3-D points are on a same plane and they form roughly a circle. I am trying to add the data of roll, pitch and yaw to the dataset such that each 24 set of point after applying the rotation angles about the axis formulates the circle in such a way that it appears to be in a tube form which is bending. The code that I am using formulates this into a surface using OpenGL. Data collected is from a IMU travelled inside a pipe.

The problem I am facing is as I apply this data to create this tube diagrammed, until rotation along Z-axis(which is roll) everything seems to be fine but when I multiply the rotation matrix along x and y axis the output is skewed and completely wrong. Can anyone point what I am doing wrong in my code

This is the code I have made for rotation

```
import numpy as np

roll = np.load("tube_roll.npy")
pitch = np.load("tube_pitch.npy")
yaw = np.load("tube_yaw.npy")
data = np.load("three_d.npy")

def matrix_angle(angle, a, b, c, d, e):
    cos = np.cos(angle)
    sin = np.sin(angle)
    zer = np.zeros((angle.shape[0], 3,3))
    zer[:, a[0], a[1]] = 1
    zer[:, b[0], b[1]] = cos
    zer[:, c[0], c[1]] = -sin
    zer[:, d[0], d[1]] = sin
    zer[:, e[0], e[1]] = cos
    return zer

rot_along_x = matrix_angle(yaw, [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2])
rot_along_y = matrix_angle(pitch, [1, 1], [0, 0], [2, 0], [0, 2], [2, 2])
rot_along_z = matrix_angle(roll, [2, 2], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1])

a  = []
for j in range(0, len(rot_along_z)):
    b = []
    for i in range(0, 24):
        dd = np.dot(rot_along_z[j], data[j, i, :])
        dd = np.dot(rot_along_y[j], dd)
        dd = np.dot(rot_along_x[j], dd)
        b.append(dd)
    a.append(b)
a = np.array(a)

np.save("three_data.npy", a)
```

And this is what I am using for making the 3-D view.

```
import OpenGL.GL as gl
import OpenGL.arrays.vbo as glvbo
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import numpy as np
import math
import sys

VS = '''
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 a_Color;

uniform mat4 u_proj;
uniform mat4 u_view;
uniform mat4 u_model;

out vec3 g_color;
void main() {

    gl_Position = u_proj * u_view * u_model * vec4(position, 1.0);
    g_color = a_Color;
}
'''

FS = '''
#version 450
in vec3 g_color;
out vec4 outColor;


void main()
{
    float d = 1.0 - gl_FragCoord.z;
    outColor = vec4(g_color * d, 1.0);
}
'''


class CreateTubeWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(CreateTubeWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('3-D Pipeline View')
        self.plot = GLPlotWidget3D(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.plot)
        [_, w] = Sb.screen_size()
        self.setGeometry(w[2]/2-50, w[3]/2-50, w[2]/2-50, w[3]/2-50)
        self.plot.show()
        self.show()



class GLPlotWidget3D(QGLWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        # QGLWidget.__init__(self)
        super(GLPlotWidget3D, self).__init__()
        self.parent_s = args[0]
        self.parent_s = self.parent_s
        self.width, self.height = 100, 100
        self.right, self.left, self.top, self.bottom = 21000, -21000, 10, -10
        self.data = np.zeros((3, 10, 2))
        self.vbo = glvbo.VBO(self.data)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.vxb, self.vyb = 0, 0
        self.count = 0
        # self.showMaximized()
        # self.show()

    def initializeGL(self):

        vs = Sb.compile_vertex_shader(VS)
        fs = Sb.compile_fragment_shader(FS)
        self.shaders_program_tube = Sb.link_shader_program(vs, fs)
        self.attrib = {a: gl.glGetAttribLocation(self.shaders_program_tube, a) for a in ['position', 'a_Color']}
        self.uniform = {u: gl.glGetUniformLocation(self.shaders_program_tube, u) for u in
                        ['u_model', 'u_view', 'u_proj']}


        self.roll = np.load('tube_roll.npy')
        self.pitch = np.load('tube_pitch.npy')
        self.yaw = np.load('tube_yaw.npy')

        self.e = np.load("three_data.npy")
        self.e = np.array(self.e, dtype=np.float32)

        self.color = np.zeros((self.e.shape[0]*self.e.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.float32)
        self.color.fill(1.0)

        self.elems = self.elements_array(self.e.shape[0], self.e.shape[1])
        self.elems = np.array(self.elems, dtype=np.int32)
        self.vertexbuffer = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertexbuffer)
        gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.e, gl.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

        self.elementbuffer = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.elementbuffer)
        gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.elems, gl.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

        self.colorbuffer = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.colorbuffer)
        gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.color, gl.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

        self.scaleZ = 30/self.e[:, :, 2].max()
        self.right, self.left, self.top, self.bottom, self.far, self.near = self.e[:, :, 1].min(), self.e[:, :,
                                                                                                   1].max(), self.e[:,
                                                                                                             :,
                                                                                                             0].min(), self.e[
                                                                                                                       :,
                                                                                                                       :,
                                                                                                                       0].max(), self.e[
                                                                                                                                 :,
                                                                                                                                 :,
                                                                                                                                 2].max(), self.e[
                                                                                                                                           :,
                                                                                                                                           :,
                                                                                                                                           2].min()
        self.far *= self.scaleZ
        self.near *= self.scaleZ
        self.angle = 0.962
        self.angle_y = 133.544
        self.zoom = True
        self.zoom_c = 90.0
        self.zoom_cv = 0.0

    def perspective_view(self):

        # projection matrix
        aspect, ta, near, far = self.width / self.height, np.tan(np.radians(self.zoom_c) / 2), 10, 50
        proj = np.matrix(((1 / ta / aspect, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1 / ta, 0, 0), (0, 0, -(far + near) / (far - near), -1),
                          (0, 0, -2 * far * near / (far - near), 0)), np.float32)

        # view matrix
        view = np.matrix(((1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, -1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, -30, 1)), np.float32)

        # model matrix
        c, s = math.cos(self.angle), math.sin(self.angle)
        cy, sy = math.cos(self.angle_y), math.sin(self.angle_y)
        scale = np.matrix(((1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, self.scaleZ, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)), np.float32)
        rotZ = np.array(((c, s, 0, 0), (-s, c, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)), np.float32)
        rotY = np.matrix(((cy, 0, sy, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (-sy, 0, cy, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)), np.float32)
        trans = np.matrix(((1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, (self.near - self.far) / 2, 1)), np.float32)
        model = scale * trans * rotY * rotZ

        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(self.uniform['u_proj'], 1, gl.GL_FALSE, proj)
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(self.uniform['u_view'], 1, gl.GL_FALSE, view)
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(self.uniform['u_model'], 1, gl.GL_FALSE, model)

    def paintGL(self):
        self.resizeGL(self.width, self.height)
        gl.glClearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0)
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        gl.glUseProgram(self.shaders_program_tube)

        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertexbuffer)

        stride = 0  # 3*self.e.itemsize
        offset = None  # ctypes.c_void_p(0)
        loc = self.attrib['position']
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, False, stride, offset)

        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.elementbuffer)

        self.perspective_view()

        loc = self.attrib['a_Color']
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.colorbuffer)
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, False, stride, offset)

        gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, self.elems.size, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)

    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.zoom:
            v = self.x-e.x()
            if v > 2:
                self.angle -= 0.01
            elif v < -2:
                self.angle += 0.01
            self.x = e.x()
            w = self.y-e.y()
            if w > 2:
                self.angle_y += 0.01
            elif w < -2:
                self.angle_y -= 0.01
            self.y = e.y()
        else:
            if e.x() > self.zoom_cv:
                self.zoom_c -= 1
            else:
                self.zoom_c += 1
            self.zoom_cv = e.x()
        self.update()

    def keyPressEvent(self, k):
        if k.key() == 16777249:
            self.zoom = False

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, k):
        if k.key() == 16777249:
            self.zoom = True

    def wheelEvent(self, w):
        e = w.angleDelta().y()
        if e > 0:
            self.zoom_c -= 1
        else:
            self.zoom_c += 1
        self.update()

    def elements_array(self, a, b):
        ring_c = b
        slice_c = a
        my_si = np.arange(slice_c - 1)
        my_elems = np.repeat(ring_c * my_si, 2)
        temp = np.empty(2 * my_si.size, my_si.dtype)
        temp[0::2] = my_si
        temp[1::2] = my_si + 1
        my_ri = np.arange(ring_c + 1)
        my_ie = np.expand_dims(my_ri % ring_c, axis=1)
        my_si = temp * ring_c + my_ie
        my_elems = np.vstack((my_elems, my_si))
        N = my_elems.shape[1] // (slice_c - 1)
        return my_elems.reshape((my_elems.shape[0], -1, N)).swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(
            (np.prod(my_elems.shape), -1)).squeeze()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    editor = CreateTubeWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I feel is I am doing something wrong with my rotation matrix as the output of rotation along Z-axis seems wrong as it's initially in a sort of 2-D plane but as we go further matrix multiplication increased the value of x and y coordinate also which should not happen.

Also below are the data file used
https://drive.google.com/file/d/177knYTSmlWcC1RQjcXf-CKICWr09MU_i/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Either use [`numpy.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) for matrix multiplications:

```py
rot_mat = np.matmul(rot_along_x, np.matmul(rot_along_y, rot_along_z))
```

or use the matrix multiplication (`@`) operator (see [`array`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) ):

```py
rot_mat = rot_along_z @ rot_along_y @ rot_along_x
```

Use [`numpy.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) to transform the vertices:

```py
a = np.array([[np.dot(v, rot_mat) for v in row] for row in data])
```

Comment: There are two problems with this approach as it's similar to what I was doing. The final a is of shape (5204, 24, 5204, 3) which is definitely not plottable. Plus the main problem that I am facing is I want to use roll, pitch and Yaw to make a 3-D pipeline and by multiplying these three rotations, value of x and Y coordinates changes so much that it should be in range in +-10 but it gets into 10^4 due to z

Comment: @AKS (5204, 24, 5204, 3), +-10, 10^4? So the problem isn't in the code, but you can't find the appropriate parameters? Pitch, yaw and roll are [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). Perhaps you've to investigate [Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).